# Laravel valet change php version doesn't work on mac os

Tags: laravel-valet

I try to change PHP version used by valet, so I execute following command:

```sh
valet use php@7.4
```

Valet return a success message: `Valet is now using php@7.4.`

But if I use phpinfo() on a .test website, I see that php is in 7.3.

I've changed the php version several times this way, it always worked. I don't understand what's wrong now...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Building on [ZecKa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861292/334457), I was able to get it working with just these commands:

```
valet stop
rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock
valet start
```

Comment: Oh....my....god.... finally. Thank you, an answer that works. Made this into a bash script. Tysm!!!!!

Comment: great! It also works with cpriego /valet-linux. (my file is at: home/.valet/valet.sock)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got [the solution on github](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/583#issuecomment-613492517)

I have to execute following commands:

```sh
valet stop
valet uninstall
rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock
valet install
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're global php is correctly set (according to your global dependencies -usually is the highest version you got) you can go with

```
valet use php@7.4 --force
```

it just stops php, nginx, and restarts them all using the correct version.